# How to pass props of one child component to another child component using parent component

Tags: reactjs, redux

[image]

1. I want to call a function in Second Child like

```js
const CallListRow = (props) => {
    return (
        <TableRow key={props.id}>
            <TableRowColumn>{props.id}</TableRowColumn>
            <TableRowColumn>{props.date}</TableRowColumn>
            <TableRowColumn>{props.callerId}</TableRowColumn>
            <TableRowColumn><Link label="Click to Call" to="javascript:void(0)" onClick={()=>dialPhone(props.phone)}  >{props.phone}</Link></TableRowColumn>
            <TableRowColumn>{props.duration}</TableRowColumn>
        </TableRow>
    );
}
```

2. And after onClick props.phone value want to get in First Child component
3. Both child components are imported in Parent component.
4. Then how to got clicked value in First Child component???

Comment: What have you tried so far? Take a look at [this article](http://andrewhfarmer.com/component-communication/) for some ideas.

Comment: From first child component call parent component method and from this method update the state pass it to child B.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to call a parent function that updates a state in the parent and then pass it as a prop to the First Child

Parent

```
..
changeSelected = (val) => {
     this.setState({selected: val})
}

render() {
  return (
     <div>
     <Firstchild selected={this.state.selected}/>
     <Secondchild changeSelected = {(val)=> {this.changeSelected(val)}}/>
     </div>
  )
}
```

FirstChild:

```
render() {
    console.log(this.props.selected);
}
```

SecondChild:

```
handleClick = (val) => {
    this.props.changeSelected(val);
}
```

---

### Update with functional components :

Parent

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState()
    
  ...

return (
  <div>
    <Firstchild selected={selected}/>
    <Secondchild changeSelected = {setSelected}/>
  </div>
 )
}
```

FirstChild:

```
useEffect(() => console.log(selected), [selected]);
```

SecondChild:

```
handleClick = (val) => changeSelected(val);
```

Comment: But i am unable to setState({}) .And after change state use this in First component.

Comment: But i am unable to setState({}) using selected value .And after change state use this in First component. Whenever its log.console() with in render.

Comment: Shubham! how to update state without click/change/call in First component. And set new value to state, received from Second component. I want to set this value in First component's input box using state like value={this.state.dialedNumber}

Comment: Pankaj, from the second component you will Receive value in the parent component, which then you pass a prop to the first component, now you need to update the state of the second component with this prop value, that you can do by  calling setState in componentWillReceiveProps function

Comment: Shubham, I have used componentWillReceiveProps function, but not change state on first click on second component. When I used like this then working fine.
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {     
      if (nextProps.dialedNumber !== this.state.dialedNumber) {
        this.setState({ dialedNumber: nextProps.dialedNumber });
      }
    }

I used if condition inside this function then working fine.

Comment: see componentWillReceiveProps is called everytime the parent re-renders and its probabely a good idea to have the if condition

Comment: Not a problem at all :), glad to have helped :)