# How to manage state between parent and child components?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, frontend

I have three components.
The first component maintains only the state of list of conditions with each condition consisting of conditioName(DropDown), operator(DropDown) and value(Textbox). The first component opens a dialog box which is the second component.

The second component displays the conditions in the dialog box. You can add row or delete row or update the conditions in the second condition. The second component has an apply button which updates the list of conditions in the first component.

Now, the second component iterates over the list of conditions over a third component which returns each row(two dropdowns, textbox and a delete icon which deletes the row). Every value I enter in the third component textbox, it rerenders the second component and it loses focus from the textbox.

I am struggling over how to maintain state during the entry of values in the third component and controlling rerender of second component?

I am fairly new to React so I would appreciate the help.

Note :- I am using reusable styled elements of material ui. Also, using a custom hook.

```
//Second Component
export interface ConditionFormProps {
  initialConditionList: ConditionFormData[];
  onUpdateConditions: (conditions: ConditionFormData[]) => void;
  onCloseDialog: () => void;
}

export default function ConditionForm({
  initialConditionList,
  onUpdateConditions,
  onCloseDialog //  Use this to close the dialog box.
}: ConditionFormProps) {
  const { conditionList, addNewRow, handleRowChange, handleDeleteRow, handleApplyChanges } =
    useConditionForm(initialConditionList, onUpdateConditions);

  return (
    <Dialog open className="editConditionForm" onClose={onCloseDialog}>
      <DialogTitle className="title">ADD SEARCH CONDITIONS</DialogTitle>
      <DialogContent>
        <div className="label-group">
          <StyledInputLabel className="label-element condition-col">Condition</StyledInputLabel>
          <StyledInputLabel className="label-element operator-col">Operator</StyledInputLabel>
          <StyledInputLabel className="label-element value-col">Value</StyledInputLabel>
        </div>
        <div className="scrollable-rows">
          {conditionList.map((cond: ConditionFormData, index) => (
            <SearchCondition
              key={`${cond.condition}-${Math.random().toString()}`}
              index={index}
              conditionRow={cond}
              onChange={(updatedCondition) => handleRowChange(index, updatedCondition)}
              onDelete={() => handleDeleteRow(index)}
            />
          ))}
        </div>

        <StyledButton
          className="add-button"
          startIcon={<AddCircleIcon className="add-icon-style" />}
          onClick={addNewRow}
        >
          Add
        </StyledButton>
        <div className="apply-button-wrapper">
          <StyledButton className="apply-button" onClick={handleApplyChanges}>
            Apply
          </StyledButton>
        </div>
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  );
}

//Third component 
type ConditionRowProps = {
  index: number;
  conditionRow: ConditionFormData;
  onChange: (condition: ConditionFormData) => void;
  onDelete: (index: number) => void;
};

export default function SearchCondition({
  index,
  conditionRow,
  onChange,
  onDelete
}: ConditionRowProps) {
  const handleInputChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    const updatedCondition: ConditionFormData = {
      ...conditionRow,
      [name]: value
    };
    onChange(updatedCondition);
  };

  const handleSelectChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent<any>) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    const updatedCondition: ConditionFormData = {
      ...conditionRow,
      [name]: value
    };
    onChange(updatedCondition);
  };

  const handleDelete = () => {
    onDelete(index);
  };

  return (
    <div className="condition-group">
      <SelectTextBox
        formControlProps={{
          className: 'condition-wrap'
        }}
        defaultItemSelected={`${conditionRow.condition}`}
        selectProps={{
          className: 'condition-input',
          id: 'condition',
          name: 'condition',
          value: conditionRow.condition,
          onChange: handleSelectChange
        }}
        menuItems={[
          {
            key: 'model',
            value: 'Model'
          },
          {
            key: 'frmwrVersion',
            value: 'Firmware Version'
          }
        ]}
      />
      <SelectTextBox
        formControlProps={{
          className: 'operator-wrap'
        }}
        defaultItemSelected={`${conditionRow.operator}`}
        selectProps={{
          className: 'operator-input',
          id: 'operator',
          name: 'operator',
          value: conditionRow.operator,
          onChange: handleSelectChange
        }}
        menuItems={[
          {
            key: 'is',
            value: 'Is'
          },
          {
            key: 'starts',
            value: 'Starts With'
          },
          {
            key: 'ends',
            value: 'Ends With'
          }
        ]}
      />
      <TextBox
        formControlProps={{
          className: 'value-wrap'
        }}
        inputProps={{
          className: 'value-input',
          placeholder: 'Enter value',
          name: 'value',
          id: 'value',
          value: conditionRow.value,
          onChange: handleInputChange
        }}
      />
      <div className="delete">
        <IconButton onClick={handleDelete}>
          <DeleteIcon width="13.67" height="15.33" />
        </IconButton>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

//Type
export type ConditionFormData = {
  condition: string;
  operator: string;
  value: string;
};

//Custom hook
const useConditionForm = (
  initialConditionList: ConditionFormData[],
  onUpdateConditions: (conditions: ConditionFormData[]) => void
) => {
  const [conditionList, setConditionList] =
    useState<ConditionFormData[]>(initialConditionList);

  const addNewRow = () => {
    setConditionList((condition) => [
      ...condition,
      {
        condition: '',
        operator: '',
        value: ''
      }
    ]);
  };

  const handleRowChange = (index: number, updatedCondition: ConditionFormData) => {
    const updatedRows: ConditionFormData[] = [...conditionList];
    updatedRows[index] = updatedCondition;
    console.log('Condition :- ' + JSON.stringify(updatedRows));
    setConditionList(updatedRows);
  };

  const handleDeleteRow = (index: number) => {
    const updatedRows = [...conditionList];
    updatedRows.splice(index, 1);
    setConditionList(updatedRows);
  };

  const handleApplyChanges = () => {
    onUpdateConditions(conditionList);
    console.log('Condition :- ' + JSON.stringify(conditionList));
  };

  return {
    conditionList,
    addNewRow,
    handleRowChange,
    handleDeleteRow,
    handleApplyChanges
  };
};

export default useConditionForm;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass props of one child component to another child component using parent component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44155573/how-to-pass-props-of-one-child-component-to-another-child-component-using-parent)

Comment: No, that is a different scenario. My components are serially hierarchical.